# Can't seem to install id3v2 on linux, doesn't seem to be any errors

Tags: linux, shell, audio, centos, id3

I'm tryin to follow the direction to install id3v2.  I installed id3lib and did not receive any errors.  I now try to do "make" and then "make install" as they suggest that I do.

I get the following responses when I go through the process.

I was under the assumption that I would be able to use the program by typing "id3v2 ....."

However, it seems that the system doesn't find the command.  Does that mean the program was not installed? If so, how would I try to find a solution?

```
[root@ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx id3v2-0.1.12]# make
g++ -Wall -I/opt/local/include/ -DVERSION="\"0.1.12\""    -c -o convert.o convert.cpp
g++ -Wall -I/opt/local/include/ -DVERSION="\"0.1.12\""    -c -o list.o list.cpp
g++ -Wall -I/opt/local/include/ -DVERSION="\"0.1.12\""    -c -o id3v2.o id3v2.cpp
g++ -Wall -I/opt/local/include/ -DVERSION="\"0.1.12\""    -c -o genre.o genre.cpp
g++ -L/opt/local/lib/  -pedantic -Wall -g -o id3v2 convert.o list.o id3v2.o genre.o -lz -lid3
[root@ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx id3v2-0.1.12]# make install
install -c -s id3v2 /opt/local/bin/id3v2
nroff -man id3v2.1 > /opt/local/share/man/man1/id3v2.1
[root@ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx id3v2-0.1.12]# id3v2
-bash: id3v2: command not found
```

I've looked at the make file itself and it says:

```
install: all
        install -c -s id3v2 ${PREFIX}/bin/id3v2
        nroff -man id3v2.1 > ${PREFIX}/share/man/man1/id3v2.1
```

The Prefix hard coded into the make file is:

> /opt/local

Now I think it must be true that it is installing it in the wrong directory.  Is it normal to adjust the Makefile? am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: Belongs on http://superuser.com

Comment: I hear various suggestions about "Get this off my site." Why not suggest I move it to unix/linux group? I have set up accounts on all of these different ones and do my best to put it where it best belongs.  Not everyone agrees where a given question belongs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely path where you installed is not in $PATH. You can either call it with the full path:

```
/opt/local/bin/id3v2
```

or add this path to your $PATH:

```
export $PATH=$PATH:/opt/local/bin
```

To make it permanent append this line to $HOME/.profile

Comment: This seems like a good answer. I'm going to go head and look into this.  Thank you for answering.

Comment: I don't really know too much about "$PATH" I'm going to do some research.

Comment: I have found: http://www.comptechdoc.org/os/linux/usersguide/linux_ugenvironment.html this says: PATH - The path the system looks in to find commands that the user has entered.

Comment: I was able to edit the Makefile to install the program to the correct directory. I have a different issue now but this is progress!